# how to remove wordpress documentation menu link in dashboard

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

[image]

I want to customize my dashboard by removing WordPress icon and it's menu on the top bar but I have no idea of how it works because am not an expert in WordPress please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom plugin and upload folder to your server with this one file in it. Make sure to save the file as exact plugin name. For example, "AdminBar.php"

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: AdminBar
Plugin URI: 
Description: Code to hide the admin bar for non-admins only.
Version: 1.0
Author: Name Here
Author URI:
*/

function hide_admin_bar_settings()
{
?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .show-admin-bar {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
<?php
}
function disable_admin_bar()
{
    if(!current_user_can('administrator'))
    {
        add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
        add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-profile.php', 'hide_admin_bar_settings' );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'disable_admin_bar', 9);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new file in the WordPress wp-content/plugins/ folder named admin-bar.php then add the following plugin header:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Admin Bar
Plugin URI: http://www.sitepoint.com/
Description: Modifies the WordPress admin bar
Version: 1.0
Author: Craig Buckler
Author URI: http://twitter.com/craigbuckler
License: MIT
*/
```

You can now activate this plugin in the WordPress administration panel. It won’t do anything yet but you can make additions, save then refresh to view the updates.

you can remove existing items with the remove_node() method. For this, we need to create a new function named update_adminbar() which is passed an WP_Admin_Bar object ($wp_adminbar). This function is called when the admin_bar_menu action hook is activated:

```
// update toolbar
function update_adminbar($wp_adminbar) {

  // remove unnecessary items
  $wp_adminbar->remove_node('wp-logo');
  $wp_adminbar->remove_node('customize');
  $wp_adminbar->remove_node('comments');

}

// admin_bar_menu hook
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'update_adminbar', 999);
```

https://www.sitepoint.com/customize-wordpress-toolbar/